# Conflict between jquery.svgdom and jquery-ui

Tags: jquery, conflict

I am contacting you because the next line (using jquery ui) did not work on my website

```
$('#result_table').hide('slide',{direction:'right'},1000);
```

I had the following error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

By removing the call to the script jquery.svgdom, the line worked.

The problem is that I need this script.

Answer (score 1):

I found that using the code from a more maintained fork 
https://github.com/twitwi/svg
helped me overcome this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found a forum where they talk about the same problem. No solution has been found yet :

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-svg-plugin-conflict-issue-with-extension-jquery-svgdom-js